# How to solve problem of Run time error while using string,Format

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to map this string by specific format into a property of my `dataModel`, so I use `string.Format()` to handle it, but I faced a **Run time error** that says:

> Input string was not in a correct format!!!

how could write it in the correct format?

```
Value = string.Format("guid{({0})}title{({1})}parameterName{({2})}", retirementItem.Guid, retirementItem.Title, retirementItem.ParameterName)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The char `{` and `}` are keywords in [string.Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.7.2#Starting).

so you have to escape them using `{{` and `}}` like:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("guid{{({0})}}title{{({1})}}parameterName{{({2})}}", Guid.NewGuid(), "title", "name"));
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the [$ - string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) syntax. A more readable and convenient syntax to create formatted strings.

If you dont need **curly brackets** in your string:

```
Value = $"guid({retirementItem.Guid})title({retirementItem.Title})parameterName({retirementItem.ParameterName})";
```

If you need them:

```
Value = $"guid{{({retirementItem.Guid})}}title{{({retirementItem.Title})}}parameterName{{({retirementItem.ParameterName})}}";
```

Comment: You could comment that the escaping works the same both in string interpolation and in string.format, in case OP wants to stick to string.format